# Remote monitoring using a non root user account with Sudo Privilege

Tags: wireshark, tcpdump

I want to remotely take tcpdump on my server with a non root user account? I tried it but doesnt seems to be working? Can someone guide me on this?

plink.exe -ssh -pw abc123 iamuser@192.168.1.1 "sudo tcpdump -ni eth0 -s 0 -w - not port 22" | "C:\Program Files\Wireshark\Wireshark.exe" -k -i -

Comment: fortunately, questions about host/server configurations are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network. Since this involves the lower layers of the network stack, you need administrative access.

Comment: the user may not have permission to use sudo, or sudo may not allow running tcpdump, but most likely sudo is asking for the user's password. (hint: use rpcapd)